# Silex/Pimple: app parameter not updated instantly by middleware

Tags: middleware, silex, pimple

I use the Silex/Pimple container to store parameters for my application. Some of those parameters are set using middleware.

Now I have come across the problem where I want to access a parameter value that should have been set through middleware. But when I output it, it still contains the old value.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
    $app['test'] = 'old value';

    $app->before(function (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, Silex\Application $app){
       // logic
       $app['test'] = 'new value';
    }, Silex\Application::EARLY_EVENT);

    echo $app['test'];
```

outputs:

```
old value
```

Does someone know how I can force the middleware to run first and then do the output? Or is there an other way to interact with the request before everything else?

Comment: Where is you echo? In a controller? Events don't get fired unti you call `$app->run()`.

Comment: @Maerlyn I use the variable to bind certain routes, so it's not in a controller. $app->run() is at the end of my application. I am now testing if I can execute those middlewares from a service provider.

Comment: Nope. Middlewares are for running code just before/after the controller.

Comment: @Maerlyn I think the only option left is to get the logic out of the middleware and place it somewhere at the beginning of my application. It's a bit more dirty but it should work.